# Apps Script Gadget Setting 100% Width and Height Bug?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I embedded a UiApp in a webpage in Google Site that contains a flextable. The width and height of the gadget can change depending on how many items are in the flextable; so when I embed it I leave the width and height blank in the gadget setting in order to get the UiApp shown 100% width and height (as instructed in the gadget setting). However, its never shown 100% height; when I check the HTML of the webpage I found that the width & the height is always set to a certain value (width="500" height="600") so my display is cut and not shown fully.

How do I ensure that my UiApp are fully shown in the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "leave blank for 100%" only works on the width attribute. You will have to determine some appropriate height for your script. I do not think there is a work around.

Furthermore, if you were able to set the height to 100%, that tells the browser to make the gadget fill 100% of the *container* (i.e. the page around the gadget). It does not tell the browser to fill 100% of the *contents inside*.

Answer (score 0):

Though it cannot be set from gadget pref, maybe you can code your Gadget code so that the frame height is updated when you change the html content. See this nice example:
https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/ui#Dyn_Height