# Dynamically show/hide Google Apps Script hosted in Google Sites Page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

After a user logs in to our private Google Sites, I want to conditionally show or hide my Google Apps Script gadget on the landing page to the user. To put another way, if the user has seen it I don't want to show it to them again until it's changed.

I am using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/), as opposed to [Google Sites Gadget](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/gadgets/site_gadgets), because I need the logged in user's email for identity purposes.

I have seen similar questions like [Google Apps Scripts have static height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878901/calling-google-apps-script-gadget-from-custom-google-gadget) and [adjusting height of Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082386/apps-script-gadget-setting-100-width-and-height-bug) but none has a solution I could use.

Comment: Alternatively, does anyone know a way to get the logged in user's email or openID in a gadget without requiring them to authorize it? It's just annoying for the user to have to authorize you to identify them after they've just logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both your question and comment are not possible.
a gas cannot be hidden or height changed. your only option is to show a blank gadget.
also a sites gadget cannot get the user's email unless you do the oauth dance which is pretty much useless: as soon as you do any changes to the gadget, like changing dimensions, the gadget url will change and that forces the oauth dance again.

Comment: Thanks, Zig. Your answer confirms my finding. I had hoped that there might be a way to identify the logged in user when the gadget publisher is the site owner but sadly that is only possible with GAS, which doesn't support dynamic height or visibility.

Sites gadgets do support dynamic height as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/ui) although I have not tested a height of zero. Unfortunately, there there is no way to identify the user without the oauth dance.

Your answer doesn't solve my problem but is a very good answer, nonetheless. Thank you

Comment: yes, ive used dinamic height and it works. the problem is, you would need to put all your logic in the gadget. If you need to identify the user, this is pretty much useless because the gadget oauth proxy breaks the saved authentication. So your only option is to implement the oauth yourself, for example inside a gadget iframe. but because the gadget and the frame live in different domains they cannot communicate, so you wont be able to tell the gadget to call gadgets.window.adjustHeight()

Comment: OK, Zig. I've accepted your answer as negative and gone down [this path](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/oauth#impl-gadget) and implemented an oauth gadget. I modified the sample so that after the user approves access, the gadget sends the request to my server with the user's openID. I use the openID to identify the user.

Comment: when you resize thw gadget (from sites editor) the oauth will be lost